# How to export PHP variables to use in separate file without running the script the variable was made in

Tags: php, search, export

So, I have a search feature on a website I made with PHP. The page that runs the search script looks like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])){

    include_once 'clients.inc.php';

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['last']);
    $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['dob']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['email']);
    $post = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['post']);

    $search = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (user_first='$first' || user_last='$last' || user_email='$email' || user_dob='$dob' || user_postcode='$post');";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $search);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){


            $client_number = $row['user_id'];
            $first_name = $row['user_first'];
            $last_name = $row['user_last'];
            $email_address = $row['user_email'];
            $date_of_birth = $row['user_dob'];
            $post_code = $row['user_postcode'];

            echo $row['user_id'] . " | " .$row['user_first'] . " " . $row['user_last'] . " | " . $row['user_email'] . " | " . $row['user_dob'] . " | " . $row['user_postcode'] . "<br>";

        }


    header("Location: ../search.php?search=results");


    } else {

        header("Location: ../search.php?search=not-found");

    }

} else {

header("Location: ../search.php?search=error");

}
```

Instead of outputting on this page, I would like to output the results on a different PHP page.

```
<p class="subtitle">First Name: </p>
<br>
<?php

echo $row['user_first'] . "<br>";

 ?>
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because the variables were not created on this page.

Could someone please tell me how I can do this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why are you redirecting or splitting it up?

Comment: sessions, or write to the redirected url would be my segestion

Comment: Put that SQL queries logic in a separate php file and include it on your search.php page. Also when a search is submitted, post it on search.php and get the query parameters or payload and process on that page.

Comment: So in the php script, it redirects back to: search.php?search=results. I have then written an if statement in search.php that says if uri=?search=results, then display "...". I just can't work out how to get the variable from the search.inc.php page into search.php

Comment: The nature of web requests are stateless. Which mean the server doesn't remember anything from one request to the next, when you do the redirect you are making a request.  As others said, you have to either use the session or the url to pass that data along to the next request.

Comment: How would i go about using the session to carry over the information?